# ActiveAdmin Dashboard Title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

How can I change Active Admin's title from 'Dashboard' to 'Tableau de bord' (french)?

Should I register the page as `Tableau de bord` instead of

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard", namespace: :admin do
```

The problem with that solution is that I will have to modify my paths.

Answer (score 0):

Na you don't have to rename the registration, just add a title in the content block.

For instance:

```
content :title => "Tableau de bord" do
  div :class => "blank_slate_container", :id => "dashboard_default_message" do
    span :class => "blank_slate" do
      span I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.welcome")
      small I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard_welcome.call_to_action")
    end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you very much! If I am not mistaken, this is not documented(?)